# How can I put this php code(if condition) in my html code?

Tags: php

I have syntax error.I don't know what to do with the specified part. Thank u in advance

here is my error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\women.php on line 74

```
echo'<table class="barname">
        <tr>
           <td>'. if ($result1['sat_1']){echo $declare;}. '</td>
        </tr>

    </table>';
```

Comment: Consider reading some very basic PHP Beginners Tutorial. And use google to find them yourself please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `if` needs to be a separate statement, like so:

```
echo '<table class="barname">
        <tr>
           <td>';

if ($result1['sat_1'])
  echo $declare;

echo '</td>
        </tr>

    </table>';
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing it properly?

```
echo 'some stuff here';
if( $result1['sat_1']) echo $declare;
echo 'more stuff';
```

You could also use a ternary operator:

```
echo 'some stuff'.($result1['sat_1'] ? $declare : 'NOTHING!').'more stuff';
```